# signalR some cookie not sent to hub -cross domain

Tags: c#, web, signalr, cross-domain

I add cookie key, and the new cookie key not sent to server .
when i console document.cookie I see the new value. but not see it in the request,

client code (angular):

```
$cookies.InternalToken = credentials.token;
_connectionHub
   .start();
```

hub code (.net c#):

```
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
connection.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
connection.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie() { Name = "InternalToken", Value = "" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Domain for the cookie

```
connection.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("InternalToken", "<value>") { Domain = new Uri(<"Host" of destination URL>);
```

EDIT
I assume you have checked the hub receives the cookie