# Adding cookies to SignalR Core requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using SignalR Core, and for architecture reasons the SignalR server stuff (Hubs and the like) are in a different domain from my main project.
Client has this code:

```
function connectToHub(url) {
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
           .withUrl(url, { headers: { "cookie": document.cookie } }).build();


    connection.on("NotificationUpdated", function (count) {
        console.log(count);
    });

    connection.start().then(function () {
        console.log('started');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

}
```

It connects to server fine, but OnConnectedAsync in my hub gets no cookies or any other credentials (Context.User.Identity.Claims is empty)

Here's OnConnectedAsync code

```
        public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, ((ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity)
               .Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Contains("email"))?.Value);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

If I put hub in the same domain as client, it works fine, but if I place it in different domain, client stops attaching cookies.

How to get the client to attach cookies?

(Alternatively, if there are different ways of mapping connectionId with User Claims, I would be fine with that too)

Comment: Have you al ready tried to autenticate signal-r by using JET access tokens? See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bearer-token-authentication

Comment: We use exactly this in our applications and it works fine.

Comment: You could try to add set domain for the cookie like this `connection.CookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie("InternalToken", "<value>") { Domain = new Uri(<"Host" of destination URL>);
`. See whether it works. Ref: [signalR some cookie not sent to hub -cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226501/10309381)

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT first, CookieContainer is from old version of SignalR, not SignalR Core, it's Cookies in SignalR Core. Second, Cookies field is only accessible in .NET code, not in JS code

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with this question in Blazor Server (Cookie authentication), and after a lot of searching, I couldn't find anything useful. Nevertheless, I managed to do it in a certain way, but I'm not sure if it's the best or even a good way.

1- Inject the IHttpContextAccessor in razor page.

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

2- Read all cookies from IHttpContextAccessor and add them to connection cookies.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var uri = new UriBuilder(Navigation.Uri);

    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), opti =>
        {
            if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
                foreach (var c in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
                {
                    opti.Cookies.Add(new Cookie(c.Key, c.Value)
                    {
                            Domain = uri.Host, // Set the domain of the cookie
                            Path = uri.Path // Set the path of the cookie
                    });
                }
        })
        .Build();

    hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
    {
        var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
        messages.Add(encodedMsg);
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

3- Now you can decorate your hub with AuthorizeAttribute.

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```